# Save multiple App Data items to one or multiple files?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file

If a program requires multiple files of the same type, say 10 settings presets, what is the typical way of storing that information in files?

So far, I have been creating a new file for each preset, so I have `Preset1.set, Preset2.set, Preset3.set`, etc. To access them I will iterate through all files in the directory and read the ones with the `.set` extension.

I'm realizing now it may be more efficient and conventional to store all presets in a file called `Preset.set`, and then write all preset configurations to the same file with some separating characters, say `~~~`.

Is there a difference in these methods? Is one preferable to the other?

Comment: I'd load the app data from a single file all at once, then just use whichever one was active.  As for file layout, I'd use serialization.  Note that you might want to add a language or technology tag to be able to get a more specific answer

Comment: I figured one file would be the way to go. I just have to implement parsing the file for the entry I'm looking for, which shouldn't be bad at all with some kind of separating character.

I am familiar with the concept of serialization, but looking at it now, I believe I am doing manually. I'm writing data to a file, and then reading it back and translating it back into objects when need be. Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing means never having to fret over separation characters or parsing text back into meaningful data.  A simple class to hold the data

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Preset
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ForeColor As Color
    Public Property BackColor As Color

    Public Property ThisItem As Integer
    Public Property ThatItem As Integer
    Public Property LastItem As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class

' elsewhere, a List of these things, so we can have many
Private Presets As New List(Of Preset)
```

Add some fake data:

```
' file path/name:
PresetsFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                              "Company", "Product", "presets.xml")

Dim p As Preset
p = New Preset With {.Name = "ziggy"}
Presets.Add(p)

' quick way, no temp var
Presets.Add(New Preset With {.Name = "User Defined"})
Presets.Add(New Preset With {.Name = "Default"})
Presets.Add(New Preset With {.Name = "Custom"})
```

Serialize the entire set of `Preset` objects to file (saving):

```
Using fs As New FileStream(PresetsFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim Xml As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Preset)))

    Xml.Serialize(fs, Presets)
End Using
```

Loading:

```
' ToDo: check if File.Exists
Using fs As New FileStream(PresetsFileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim Xml As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Preset)))

    Presets = CType(Xml.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Preset))
End Using

' show none were lost:
For Each ps As Preset In Presets
    Console.WriteLine(ps.Name)
Next
```

Output:

> ziggy
>   User Defined
>   Default
>   Custom

That's it!  Save or load an entire list of objects in less than 5 lines of code.

1. Note that there are different kinds of serializers, this is just one.  I tend to favor binary serialization so the user cannot hunt down the file and edit values perhaps to illegal values which may cause the app to crash.
2. The `<Serializable>` attribute or others may be required depending on which serializer (json, binary formatter, Protobuf-net) you use.
3. Some of the serializers also require a simple constructor (`Sub New` with no parameters).
4. The methods to `Save` and `Load` can be defined as `Shared` methods in the `Preset` class.  Especially so if there was a collection class (not just a `List`).

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind, I had another question about serializing objects with objects in them (as fields). If you have the time, an answer would be greatly appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388702/xml-serializing-objects-that-contain-other-objects-recursive-serialization