# XML Serializing objects that contain other objects (recursive serialization)

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have a class called `Port Characteristics` that is as follows:

```
<Serializable()> Public Class PortCharacteristics

    Public portNum As Int16

    Public bRate As Integer

    Public par As String

    Public len As String

    Public stopb As String

    Public flow As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal valPortNum As Int16, ByVal valBRate As Integer, ByVal valPar As String, ByVal valLen As String, ByVal valStopb As String, ByVal valFlow As String)
        portNum = valPortNum
        bRate = valBRate
        par = valPar
        len = valLen
        stopb = valStopb
        flow = valFlow
    End Sub

End Class
```

I also have another class, `Profile`, that contains `Port Characteristics`:

```
 <Serializable()> Public Class Profile

    Public profileName As String

    Public chars As PortCharacteristics

    Public Property PortChar As PortCharacteristics
        Get
            Return chars
        End Get
        Set(value As PortCharacteristics)
            chars = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal profName As String, ByVal portNum As Int16, ByVal baud As Integer, ByVal par As String, ByVal length As String, ByVal stopB As String, ByVal flowCon As String)

        Name = profName

        PortChar = New PortCharacteristics(portNum, baud, par, length, stopB, flowCon)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I serialize the Profile class like this:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("profiles.xml") Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("profiles.xml")
End If

Using fs As New FileStream("profiles.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim Xml As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Profile)))
    Xml.Serialize(fs, ProfileList)
End Using
```

Is it possible to serialize objects within objects in XML in the same file, or do I have to use binary or some other type of serialization?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second class?  That wont compile as is, `PortCharString` for instance references non existent properties/members

Comment: Oh, sorry I took out some Properties in PortCharString to make it more readable for the question.

PortCharacteristics is a set of characteristics, and PortProfile is a collection of different settings that include the characteristics in PortCharacteristics.

Comment: `PortProfile is a collection` no it is not.  It is one PortItem with a ProfileName added to it.  Also what is `ProfileList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no recursion involved, you "simply" have one object nested in another.  Second, the `Profile` class code is wrong - it references members which do not exist; none of those listed on `PortCharString` exist on the other class.

I cannot tell what role `Profile` plays.  As shown, it is just a wrapper which adds a Name to a `PortCharacteristics` item.  That could simply be added to the other class.  If `Profile` was meant to assign a name and store several items, it lacks any sort of collection object.  There are other issues, but I *suspect* the problem is here:

```vb
Dim Xml As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Profile)))
Xml.Serialize(fs, ProfileList)
```

We can't tell from what is posted if `ProfileList` is another Type or an object variable.  This works (I changed some names):

```vb
Dim pList As New List(Of PortProfile)

pList.Add(New PortProfile("COM9:", 9, 1200, "E", "7", "1", "X"))
pList.Add(New PortProfile("COM13:", 13, 300, "E", "8", "1", "X"))

Using fs As New FileStream(PortProFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim Xml As New XmlSerializer(pList.GetType)
    Xml.Serialize(fs, pList)
End Using
```

Make sure that the `Type` used in the `XmlSerializer` constructor matches the object variable being used, and it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, the declaration of ProfileList is as List (of Profile).

You're right, the Profile class just wraps PortCharacteristics in a class, but contains some other information too in addition to PortCharacteristics.

Comment: It's giving me an InvalidOperationError in the first serialization line you mentioned (There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List), but, like I said, ProfileList is New List (Of Profile). Is there anything more I can tell you to parse this out?

Comment: Well, the devil may be in the details.  I can get a version of what you posted to serialize/deserialize just fine.  There could be something else there, which you havent shared, which results in a problem.  Drill into the inner exception to get more information. OTOH, the Item could contain that extra info and a method or property return the subset as needed.  A 1:1 relationship isnt usually all that useful.

Comment: The problem is that it's not writing the PortCharacteristic object to the XML file, and it doesn't crash (I had accidently commented out the parameterless constructor that caused the previous error). It simply writes <PortChar />
  </Profile> in the XML file, and doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Sounds like an implementation issue (or perhaps scope) - are you sure you have some items in the list?  How did you add them?  Your item class just has public *fields* not properties, that should not matter in this case, but it can.  My class: http://pastebin.com/kED5zvh3  You should be able to paste that little snippet from the answer into a button click to test it (using your names, of course).

Comment: Wow, I think I've found my problem, and its a brainfart.

All of my properties on PortCharacteristics are ReadOnly. Adding Set statements and seeing if that fixes it, but I bet it will!

Comment: Yep, you were totally right. It was a problem with the properties of PortCharacteristics and them not being ReadOnly. Of course I would remove those to make the code easier to read ;/ Greatly appreciated, AGAIN.

Comment: Although at the moment it stops compiling on the line ProfileList = CType(Xml.Deserialize(fs), List(of Profile)) with some first chance exception InvalidCastException and Reflection.TargetInvocationException, so I'm looking at that now.